# gh-pages 404 errors with deploy a react app

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I have 404 errors when I tried to deploy my react app to gh-pages.
Here is my github - https://github.com/XAHTC/test-app/, and gh-pages - https://github.com/XAHTC/test-app/tree/gh-pages.

It is a screenshot of errors:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to add a [homepage](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) property to your package.json.

Comment: @WebbH it added